# How to create a semi transparent popup box?

Tags: javascript, popup, html, transparent

I don't know javascript well at all, I have not studied it, yet. I am writing a webpage for a small business, I know HTML and CSS reasonably well.

My question; is what code can I use, (presumably some java script) so that when I click a bit of text (inside a ul tag) a semi-transparent/black box (*) with rounded edges appears inside the tab (not a new window) that will display some text. It should have a close button too.

In this case, under the menu: Contact Us, I have:

```
Email
Phone
Postal Address.
```

I'm aiming to get them all to be clickable and, without changing to a new page, display the email/phone/address.

Any help/tips/comments are much appreciated ;)  If you aren't sure what I mean, I can create a mockup in GIMP ;)

(*)I'm sought of aiming at a similar appearance to the background of the notification menu in android 4.1+(/*)

Comment: Are you using any libraries?

Comment: Well formatted question. Unfortunately, it's a question that will likely be closed. I suggest taking a look at the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/popup/example.php

Comment: Use jQuery and colorbox. It would be the fastest, least painful way to achieve this: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 2):

JQuery `overlay.` Or use my code.
http://jsfiddle.net/sGeVT/10/

Answer (score 1):

So if you look into [JQuery](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) they have this function already built in. Then you could edit the CSS and use RGBA and opacity to make it transparent

Comment: THanks, that's EXACTLY what I wanted. :)